# What is difference between [NSObject: AnyObject] and AnyObject in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In default template we can find the following code:

`func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

Just wonder why here it is [NSObject: AnyObject]? rather than AnyObject? What's the different between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NSObject: AnyObject]` is a dictionary that allows you to access one object by providing a different object. Simply putting `AnyObject` means that your program doesn't know whether the parameter is a dictionary, a string, and int, or what, and therefore doesn't know how to handle it. Besides, the OS calls that method so you know you are getting a `[NSObject: AnyObject]` every time, so why not have the parameter type that.

Comment: For clarity: Strings and Ints are structs, not classes, in Swift. If you assign one of those to an `AnyObject` variable, the object will get converted to NSString or NSNumber, respectively.